# How to do an automatic login for a signed-in FirebaseAuth User on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Using Swift5.3.1, XCode12.2, iOS14.2,

I am trying to create an auto-login for my Firebase-Auth-user in my iOS App.

From the [Firebase documentation for iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), it says:

[image]

Therefore my initial implementation after reading the documentation was as follows:

Inside AppDelegate.swift's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method I had the following if-statement implemented that checked for the nil-status of the currentUser. If non-nil then the routing to the mainscreen took place.

```
// old Autologin
if let _ = Auth.auth().currentUser {
    self.changeRootViewController(.mainscreen, animated: false)
}
```

With my above implementation, everything seemed to work. The Auto-login behaviour did work fine.

However, I realised that the auto-login would keep forever (i.e. after two weeks without app-usage, the non-nil check would still pass whenever I opened the app again).

**I asked myself: Isn't the auto-login supposed to expire ?**

Moreover, currentUser-properties (such as "isEmailVerified") did not seem to reflect on the FirebaseAuth status at play. For example, if a user pressed the Email-Verification Link then it did not affect the `Auth.auth().currentUser.isEmailVerified` property at all ! The auto-login would show old properties on the Auth.auth().currentUser

Then I found the following method on the FirebaseAuth User-class :

[image]

And here my newest implementation that I deducted form the `reload` documentation:

```
// new Autologin
Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload(completion: { (error) in
    if let error = error {
        log.error("Auth.auth().currentUser reload faild with error: \(String(describing: error))")
    } else if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        self.changeRootViewController(.mainscreen, animated: false)
    }
})
```

Questions:

1. Is it possible that the [Firebase-documentation about currently signed-in user check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) is completely misleading concerning automatic login on iOS ?
2. Is it correct that an automatic login is better done by using the [FirebaseAuth User-class method `reload`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/User#reloadcompletion:) in order to update the Auth.auth().currentUser fields ?
3. Or is there an even better way of doing an automatic login on iOS with a FirebaseAuth User ?

Comment: @frankvanpuffelen answer is on point (as usual) but a lot of this is covered in the documentation. Check out [user life cycle](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#the_user_lifecycle) and [manage user sessions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions) which cover the expirations etc in more detail. *Firebase Authentication sessions are long lived* - they will persist between restarts, shut downs etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication automatically persists the user authentication state (to the keychain on iOS) and tries to restore it when the app is restarted. In addition it refreshes the authentication state (more specifically: the ID token that it's based on) every hour. As long as these refreshes succeed, the authentication session won't auto-expire.

To force an update of the ID token, and thus the local user profile, you can call `reload` on the user object. This is most commonly done to get up to date values for properties that are updated on the server out-of-band (so in a way that the client can't know about), such as `isEmailVerified`.

Comment: If you write "server-out-of-band": Do I understand correctly that only a sign-out / sign-in on the same device does actually bring the Auth.auth().currentUser in alignment with the server ? And do I understand that the `Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload(completion: {...}` is a second way of bringing the server in alignment ?

Comment: And question 2: you wrote "As long as these refreshes succeed, the authentication session won't auto-expire.": My question: do these refreshes succeed even if the App is completely closed ? Or why do you explain that an App can be completely shut-down for 2 weeks and the auto-login would still work ? (i.e. Auth.auth().currentUser != nil after 2 weeks) ???

Comment: 1) Signing in gets a new ID token, so gets you the latest data from the server. The hourly refresh also gets you the latest data, as does forcing a reload of the ID token in your code. 2) Refreshes only happens when the app is active. So if you don't use the app for 2 weeks, the token won't be refreshed. But then when you open the app again, it gets the credentials from the keychain and requests an updated ID token straight away, so the user is still signed in (unless the refresh gets rejected, for example: because you've disabled/deleted the account).

Comment: Thank you Frank!  My last question 3:  I found `result.claims` with the `getIDTokenResult`-method on `Auth.auth().currentUser`. Do I understand correctly that there is a way to get, at least, the claimed-server-state (that eventually will fulfil within an hour) with these `result.claims` ?? i.e. example to get the claimed `isEmailVerified` value: `if let emailVerified = result?.claims["email_verified"] as? Bool { ... }`  I assume that all `Auth.auth().currentUser` properties do have a correspoinding claim (that prognoses the state we have within the next hour), right ?

Comment: The docs say: "Stores the entire payload of claims found on the ID token. This includes the standard reserved claims as well as custom claims set by the developer via the Admin SDK", so it sounds like both built-in and custom claims should be there. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AuthTokenResult#claims